# How can I generate post link in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to generate a link that will use post method

```
<%= link_to "guess", :action => "submit_guess", :method => "post" %>
```

But when I click on that link I am getting

```
No route matches [GET] "/guess/submit_guess"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= button_to 'guess', action: 'submit_guess' %>
```

Or, if you have JS enabled:

```
<%= link_to 'guess', action: 'submit_guess', method: :post %>
# note the symbol
```

(It's better to use `button_to` and then style it with css if necessary)

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to "guess", {:action => "submit_guess"}, :method => "post" %>
```